# how to extract only words from sentences?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract just words from strings as below but somehow it doesn't work, i have the current and expected output, any guidance on how to fix it?

```
import re

string1 = 'test,'

string2 = 'OS_LOG_ALERT("received'

string3 = 'target.\\n\");'

line1 = re.sub(r'\W+', '', string1)

line2 = re.sub(r'\W+', '', string2)

line3 = re.sub(r'\W+', '', string3)

print (line1)
print (line2)
print (line3)
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
checkivarsfDriversetLinkChangedEventDatakWiFiLinkDown
OS_LOG_ALERTreceived
targetn
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
check ivars fDriver setLinkChangedEventData kWiFiLinkDown
OS_LOG_ALERT received
target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `findall` instead:

```
import re

string1 = 'check:ivars->fDriver->setLinkChangedEventData(kWiFiLinkDown,'

string2 = 'OS_LOG_ALERT("received'

string3 = 'target.\\n\");'

line1 = ' '.join(re.findall(r'\w{2,}', string1))

line2 = ' '.join(re.findall(r'\w{2,}', string2))

line3 = ' '.join(re.findall(r'\w{2,}', string3))

print (line1)
print (line2)
print (line3)
```

Output:

```
check ivars fDriver setLinkChangedEventData kWiFiLinkDown
OS_LOG_ALERT received
target
```

*Note: I filtered words with 2 or more characters only to get rid of the `n`*